# How do I enable apache snapshot access within maven

Tags: java, maven

How do I enable access to the Apache commons snapshots from my maven settings configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

add to your `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>repository.apache.org.snapshots</id>
    <name>Apache snapshots repo</name>
    <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

In your question, you ask about "settings" but it's a bad idea to declare this repo. in your `settings.xml`.

Comment: because you probably don't want this repo to be searched every time maven does an artifact search

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the repositories section of the Maven settings reference.

http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories